# How to use GroupBy Data in View - ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: c#, entity-framework, group-by, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following LINQ code.

```
public List<IGrouping<Guid, ProfileImage>> GetAllUser()
{
    return _profileImageRepository.QueryProfileImage()
        .GroupBy(g => g.UserId)
        .ToList();
}
```

The idea is that it will retrieve all users' profile pictures, but if a user has more than one image, only the last image to be returned.

I'm not sure it is right, but that's not my biggest problem.

In my controller, I have the following code.

```
_homeViewModel.ProfileImages = _profileImageService.GetAllUser();
```

ViewModel:

```
public List<IGrouping<Guid, ProfileImage>> ProfileImages { get; set; }
```

My big question is, how do I use this in my view, so that I can print the correct info.

When I look at the data in the immidiate Windows so it looks like this:

```
Model.ProfileImages
Count = 2
    [0]: {System.Data.Objects.ELinq.InitializerMetadata.Grouping<System.Guid,Zipr.Models.ProfileImage>}
    [1]: {System.Data.Objects.ELinq.InitializerMetadata.Grouping<System.Guid,Zipr.Models.ProfileImage>}
```

I have tried to do this:

```
<ul>
    @foreach (var image in Model.ProfileImages)
    {
        <li>
            <img src="@Url.Content(String.Format("~/Content/uploads/thumbs/{0}", image.ThumbPath))" alt="" />
        </li>
    }
</ul>
```

Anyone have a solution how I can access my Properties ThumbPath and more?

Comment: Could you show us your model classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't seem you're interested in ID; so change this to return a list of `ProfileImage`

```
public List<ProfileImage> GetAllUser()
{
    return _profileImageRepository.QueryProfileImage()
        .GroupBy(g => g.UserId)
        .Select(u => u.First() } 
        .ToList();
}
```

Now when your view loops over the images it will be actually getting a `ProfileImage` Object and not an instance of an `IGrouping`